# What's the best way to add double quotes in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, escaping, quotes

I have the following.

```sql
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

ALTER  FUNCTION doublequotestring(@str nvarchar(1998)) RETURNS nvarchar(4000) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ret nvarchar(4000),
           @sq  char(1)
   SELECT @sq = '"'
   SELECT @ret = replace(@str, @sq, @sq + @sq)
   RETURN(@sq + @ret + @sq)
END

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238369(SQL.80).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
alter function doublequotestring(@str nvarchar(1998)) returns nvarchar(4000)
begin
    return '"' + replace(@str, '"', '""') + '"'
end
```